# Bro convert hex string to int

Tags: bro

I am using bro to read bytes directly of the payload of a packet.

I have a string value "\x10" and I want to get the decimal value of off that.

I know that bro support directly printing hex to decimal:

```
print 0x10;
```

Question is, how do I convert that string similarly to its integer version?

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do is strip off the "\x" portion, and run it through 2 BIFs:

```
bytestring_to_count(hexstr_to_bytestring("10"));
```